# How to change the background color of Selected item in CollectionView? .Net Maui

Tags: c#, maui

In Android, the default color is orange but i dont know how to change it.
I tried the demo code of the official Microsoft's Docs, but is doesn´t work.

```
//Xaml//
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource OfferProductStyle}"
                ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid,1"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                x:Name="MyCollectionView">
</CollectionView>
```

[My CollectionView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u07s8.png)

Comment: I just want to warn you about something. IOS and Android will render differently. Test on real devices. Also, if you change the visibility of those controls, some bugs start to appear.  I was toying with it few months ago. For everything but the most basic cases, I would not put it in production.

Answer (score 16):

[CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.collectionview?view=net-maui-7.0) has a `Selected` `VisualState` that can be used to initiate a visual change to the selected item in the [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.collectionview?view=net-maui-7.0). A common use case for this `VisualState` is to change the background color of the selected item, which is shown in the following **XAML** example:

```
<CollectionView SelectionMode="Single"> 
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                <VerticalStackLayout>
                     <Label Text="{Binding}"/>

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState Name="Normal"></VisualState>
                                <VisualState Name="Selected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightSkyBlue"></Setter>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

            <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>1</x:String>
                    <x:String>2</x:String>
                    <x:String>3</x:String>
                    <x:String>4</x:String>
                    <x:String>5</x:String>   
                </x:Array>
            </CollectionView.ItemsSource>         
</CollectionView>
```

For more deatils, you can refer to this official docs:[Change selected item color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/selection?view=net-maui-7.0#change-selected-item-color).

Comment: Same approach will wotk for ListView also ?

Comment: @Suchith I don't think it will work. You can give it a try. [Visual states in .NET MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/visual-states#visual-states-in-net-maui)

Comment: what about multiple selection? is this solution works with multiple selection?

Answer (score 0):

For this specific issue, that orange color is a platform specific color. It is found in your Android project head: Resources/values/Styles.xml. If you want to makes sure to take care of all these color cases, I would suggest replacing your contents of that xml file with the following (replace #FFFFFFFF with the actual color you want though) :

```
<resources>
   <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
       <item name="android:colorPressedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
       <item name="android:colorLongPressedHighlight">@color/ListViewHighlighted</item>
       <item name="android:colorFocusedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
       <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
       <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
  </style>
    <color name="ListViewSelected">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="ListViewHighlighted">#FFFFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean here? where does this go? Why are you targeting the action bar than the collectionview?

Comment: This is following android's [material styling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/material-theme). The action bar is not the targeted control, but the name of the overlying parent theme to the application. If you have a custom theme of anything else defined, you can apply it there instead. The important part is the overwrite the android:colorPressedHighlight. As for where it goes: it is found in your Android project head: Resources/values/Styles.xml file